# Why can logging on to Oracle leak memory?

Tags: c, oracle, winapi

I am writing a service to send SMS. A separate thread is launched periodically for this. I connect to SQL server, get fresh messages, send them to Oracle SMS server database for further processing and then disconnect from both databases. My problem is that, if I connect to Oracle and then disconnect, total memory consumption increases overtime (not every launch). If I omit this step (logging on to Oracle), everything is OK. I have commented out everything except connecting and disconnecting. I use Oracle client 19c.
Here is the code:

```
    DWORD Timer(LPVOID lpParameter){
    DWORD SMSTaskResult = 0;
    HANDLE SMSTaskThread;
    while (1)
    {
        //WriteLog(LOG_RECORD_TYPE_INFO, 1, "Running task");

        SMSTaskThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) &RunSMSTask,0,0,0);
        if (SMSTaskThread == NULL) {
            WriteLog(LOG_RECORD_TYPE_ERROR, 1, "Unable to run SMS Task. Error creating thread"); SvcStopSuccess = false; SetEvent(SvcStopEvent); return 1;
        }
        else { 
            WaitForSingleObject(SMSTaskThread, INFINITE);
            if (!GetExitCodeThread(SMSTaskThread, &SMSTaskResult)) {
                WriteLog(LOG_RECORD_TYPE_ERROR, 1, "Unable to get task result. Exiting");  CloseHandle(SMSTaskThread); SvcStopSuccess = false; 
                SetEvent(SvcStopEvent);return 1;
            }
            CloseHandle(SMSTaskThread);
            if (SMSTaskResult != 0) { WriteLog(LOG_RECORD_TYPE_ERROR, 1, "Critical error. Stopping timer");  SvcStopSuccess = false;  SetEvent(SvcStopEvent); return 1; }
            
        }

        Sleep(run_interval);
    }
    return 0;}
DWORD RunSMSTask(LPVOID LpParameter){
    int ExitCode = 0; if (TaskRunning) return 0;
    hOCISvc = NULL;
    TaskRunning = true;
    WriteLog(LOG_RECORD_TYPE_INFO, 1, "Running task");
    RetCode = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)atlant, SQL_NTS, NULL,0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT); 
    if (RetCode != SQL_SUCCESS) { HandleDiagnosticRecord2(hDbc, SQL_HANDLE_DBC, RetCode,NULL); if (RetCode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {ExitCode = -1; goto Exit;}}
    OCIRetCode = OCILogon2(hOCIEnv, hOCIError, &hOCISvc, (text*)oracle_user, strlen(oracle_user), (text*)oracle_password, strlen(oracle_password), (text*)oracle_host, strlen(oracle_host),OCI_DEFAULT);
    if (OCIRetCode != OCI_SUCCESS) {
        HandleOracleError2(hOCIError, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, OCIRetCode, NULL); if (OCIRetCode != OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)  goto Exit;
    }
Exit:
    if (hOCISvc) { OCIRetCode = OCILogoff(hOCISvc, hOCIError);     if (OCIRetCode != OCI_SUCCESS) {
        HandleOracleError2(hOCIError, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, OCIRetCode, NULL); if (OCIRetCode != OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)  goto Exit;
    }
    }
    if (hDbc)
    {
        RetCode = SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
        if (RetCode != SQL_SUCCESS) {
            HandleDiagnosticRecord2(hDbc, SQL_HANDLE_DBC, RetCode, NULL);
        }
    }
    TaskRunning = false;
    return ExitCode;
}
```

Comment: How are you getting your `hDbc`, and are you called `SQLFreeHandle()` on it?

Comment: what sense create `RunSMSTask` thread and than just wait on it ? why not direct call `RunSMSTask` ?

Comment: Have you verified that this is a genuine resource leak? A cache implementation can exhibit the same observable memory consumption pattern as a resource leak would.

Comment: I tried without creating a separate thread, but that did not help. A separate thread is for a case if I need to send multiple messages at once. I am not sure if I need it. I did other jobs along this pattern (autodialer, mail sender etc).

The service originally consumed under 6 megabytes of ram. Now, after a day, it is 7,6-7,8 megabytes of ram, jumps and falls, but approximately on the same level.

What is strange that, in case of SQL odbc connection I did not see such an increase of memory usage, but with OCI it is about 2 megabytes of RAM. It looks like something is cached.

Comment: If I compare this service with those, written in C#, the amount of RAM consumed is times less, but still it is too much comparing with regular services.

Comment: Going from under 6 megabytes to around 8 megabytes is not a big deal at all; if it kept growing 2 megabytes per day, for a month, then might be a problem.